# Java process - find which class is creating pipes

Tags: java, linux

One of my process is getting 'too many open files' error. Using 'lsof' I see many (~5000) pipes, e.g. below sample. Is there a way to find which class is creating so many pipes? From my limited understanding, opening connections, streams would result in creating pipes. I am not sure if it's my class or one of the many dependant jars. Thanks.

```
lr-x------ 1 user general 64 2016-02-26 18:18 990 -> pipe:[427246223]
l-wx------ 1 user general 64 2016-02-26 18:18 991 -> pipe:[427246223]
lr-x------ 1 user general 64 2016-02-26 18:18 992 -> eventpoll:[427246224]
lr-x------ 1 user general 64 2016-02-26 18:18 993 -> pipe:[427246492]
l-wx------ 1 user general 64 2016-02-26 18:18 994 -> pipe:[427246492]
lr-x------ 1 user general 64 2016-02-26 18:18 995 -> eventpoll:[427246493]
lr-x------ 1 user general 64 2016-02-26 18:18 996 -> pipe:[427247239]
l-wx------ 1 user general 64 2016-02-26 18:18 997 -> pipe:[427247239]
lr-x------ 1 user general 64 2016-02-26 18:18 998 -> eventpoll:[427247240]
lr-x------ 1 user general 64 2016-02-26 18:19 999 -> pipe:[427247760]

lsof -p <pid>

java    22918 user 1409r  0000               0,10        0 427328545 unknown inode type
java    22918 user 1410r  FIFO                0,6          427329412 pipe
java    22918 user 1411w  FIFO                0,6          427329412 pipe
java    22918 user 1412r  0000               0,10        0 427329413 unknown inode type
java    22918 user 1413r  FIFO                0,6          427329799 pipe
java    22918 user 1414w  FIFO                0,6          427329799 pipe
java    22918 user 1415r  0000               0,10        0 427329800 unknown inode type
java    22918 user 1416r  FIFO                0,6          427330295 pipe
java    22918 user 1417w  FIFO                0,6          427330295 pipe
java    22918 user 1418r  0000               0,10        0 427330296 unknown inode type
java    22918 user 1419r  FIFO                0,6          427331472 pipe
java    22918 user 1420w  FIFO                0,6          427331472 pipe
java    22918 user 1421r  0000               0,10        0 427331473 unknown inode type
java    22918 user 1422r  FIFO                0,6          427332784 pipe
java    22918 user 1423w  FIFO                0,6          427332784 pipe
java    22918 user 1424r  0000               0,10        0 427332785 unknown inode type
java    22918 user 1425r  FIFO                0,6          427333054 pipe
java    22918 user 1426w  FIFO                0,6          427333054 pipe
java    22918 user 1427r  0000               0,10        0 427333055 unknown inode type
java    22918 user 1428r  FIFO                0,6          427334637 pipe
java    22918 user 1429w  FIFO                0,6          427334637 pipe
java    22918 user 1430r  0000               0,10        0 427334638 unknown inode type
```

UPDATE: 
below is an exception when i tried to connect to this process via JMX. The process keeps running, but it appears in hang state- no logs rolling.

```
23-Feb-2016 07:22:10 sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop executeAcceptLoop
WARNING: RMI TCP Accept-15968: accept loop for ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,port=0,localport=15968] throws
java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:408)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:462)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:430)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:369)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:341)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: What is the 'too many files open' error? Does that manifest as an exception? It could be worthwhile to check your code and make sure you are closing resources appropriately.

Comment: A a guess you aren't closing Selectors. I'm not aware of anything else in Java that uses pipes.

Comment: added 'too many open files' exception. I have checked my code and close all the connections. I am trying to find the offending piece of code, most likely in a dependant jar.

Comment: Did you figure it out ?